# How to show image in ICS file description generated through PHP

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

This is my ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:https://www.google.com/
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
TZ:+00
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:https://www.google.com/
DTSTAMP:20180809T000000
DTSTART:20180809T113000
LOCATION:Doubletree by Hilton, Norwalk, CA
DTEND:20180809T133000
SUMMARY:State of the Nation
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML><BODY><p><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-9565" src="https://www.test.org/wp-content/uploads/state-of-the-nation.png" alt="" width="742" height="881"></p><br/><a href="https://www.test.org/event/state-of-the-nation/">Click here</a></BODY></HTML>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

All the content is shown proper except the image.I checked on outlook 2013  2017 but image doesn't appear in the description though image url is correct & image is present.Can anyone help?

Comment: Outlook often blocks the download of images from external sources. Did you check that? Did you try loading it in any other calendar client (e.g. Google calendar or something) for comparison? Did you try inserting any other content into the HTML to see if it displays correctly? AFAIK Outlook 2013 doesn't like HTML in calendar items. Later versions may have improved on this.

Comment: I checked on google calendar but image doesn't appear there too.Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Should I assume that the image link you've given above is just a sample for the sake the question? Because the URL doesn't exist, so I hope it's not the real one you are testing with.

Comment: yes it is for testing. this is the actual image url : https://www.cerritos.org/wp-content/uploads/state-of-the-nation.png

Comment: Have you tried base64-encoding the image data and including it that way instead?

Comment: No. this image is part of description.User adds image in the Post description & it's not a separate field.
Did you find any issue with my ics file?

Comment: Well I'm not 100% certain, hence why I'm asking you to test with base-64 instead of providing a hyperlink. I suspect that maybe calendars do not like embedding images from remote URLs - could be a security feature. Most email clients disable that by default as well, although usually it can be re-enabled with a user setting. I'm saying maybe it's not so much the ICS which is the issue, but the HTML content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174709/discussion-between-user2431224-and-adyson).

Comment: The spec does not specifically allow for images in the description (or even html for that matter).   There may be varying support oor success in applications dealing well with what is in the description.